# How to use wildcards correctly in Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure where is 1 variable as input.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spExample
@name NVARCHAR(60) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT [name], [dom] 
    FROM [DomName]
    INNER JOIN [Domain]
            ON LEFT([name], 1)+'%' LIKE @name +'%'  
END
```

For now It returning records from table if first letter of the record is as input. For example if record in table is "Test", excecuting following procedure : `EXEC spExample 'T'` It returns correct record.

But It should return record even If I type `T`, `Te`, `Tes`, or `Test` as procedure inputs. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `ON [name] LIKE @name + '%'` ? You don't need to add the percentage sign to the left operator, only the right. Also, why are you joining here?

Comment: You're using LEFT([name], 1) so you're only ever going to check the first letter returned. Why don't you try LEFT([name], Len(@name)) although it's not ideal

Comment: Sorry mistake, `@name` should be instead of `@var`, edited.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I have very big procedure, I just wrote this as an example.

Comment: @POHH I've used LEFT, because don't had more ideas how to do that

Comment: @Infinity: Whats the relationship between these two tables?

Comment: One of these table contains domain information, other websites information

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: @marc_s thank you for supporting, I know It, as I said before I just quickly wrote here an example to show my problem. I have big procedure which Is written correctly, this is just example of the fragment :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Select column1,column2 from Table1 where column1 like '''+'%'+ @var +'%'+'''
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you trying to join two tables using variable.

```
SELECT [name], [dom] 
FROM [DomName]
    INNER JOIN [Domain] ON [name] LIKE +'%' + @var +'%'
```

I believe this should go to the where condition

```
SELECT [name], [dom] 
FROM [DomName]
    INNER JOIN [Domain] ON [[[Some condition here based on two table relationship]]]
Where [name] LIKE +'%' + @var +'%'
```